# Select rows and union two columns to one except certain value

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-3.33

I have a three column table

```
CREATE TABLE "colls" (
    "w1"    TEXT,
    "w2"    TEXT,
    "coocc_freq"    INTEGER
)
```

| w1 | w2 | coocc_freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s | o | 2 |
| o | d | 10 |
| a | q | 8 |
| w | a | 8 |
| s | w | 14 |
| a | s | 20 |

I just want to get w1 and w2 with s value:

```
SELECT * FROM colls where w1='s' or w2='s' order by coocc_freq desc
```

| w1 | w2 | coocc_freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | s | 20 |
| s | w | 14 |
| s | o | 2 |

How I can to keep just two columns? w1 + w2 - `s` = w

I.e I want to skip `s` value and get something like:

| w | coocc_freq |
| --- | --- |
| a | 20 |
| w | 14 |
| o | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(w1, 's'), w2) AS w
       coocc_freq
FROM colls 
WHERE 's' IN (w1, w2);
```